# TFS custom build agent scope logs being overwritten.

Tags: logging, tfs, custom-build

We have a custom build which makes use of our build agents multiple times throughout the build process (this was the design of the creator who is no longer at our company). We've just recently discovered that the ActivityLog.AgentScope.*Build-Agent-ID*.xml logs are being overwritten when the same agent gets used again later on in the process. We end up with only one log, which is from the last instance of the agent being used.

For example, an agent gets called twice during the build process. The first call finishes and the log is there, later on the second call occurs and overwrites the previous log using the same file name (ActivityLog.AgentScope.*Build-Agent-ID*.xml)

So naturally, we're wanting to retain all logs by adding a timestamp to the log file name. But no where do we see in the custom build where these logs are being created. We've searched through [MDSN's Team Foundation Build Activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg265783%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [ALM Rangers: TF Build Customization Guide](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/), but with no luck.

We're figuring that build agents weren't meant to be used multiple times in the process of a custom build. But now that we rely on this custom build, is there a way to work around this to keep all of the agent scope logs? We want to avoid reworking the custom build to use an agent only once.

Comment: May be if you mention the root issue of why you are trying to call the build agents multiple times, we might have suggestions or better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same Problem. This is an issue from TFS (still existing in Version 2013). I created an Issue at Microsoft: [Issue Link!](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5214207-logging-issue-with-multiple-agentscopes-on-same-bu)

Please vote the Bug: [Bug at Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811774/logging-issue-with-multiple-agentscopes-on-same-buildagent)

Comment: I'm surprised there was already a response from Microsoft on the bug you entered. Hopefully they'll respond with an answer soon!

Comment: This was posted by Microsoft just a few days ago: "This is a known limitation in TFS 2013 we are looking at addressing it for v.Next". It's not the answer I was looking for, but it is an answer, so I'll accept yours now :)